# Python boto3 DynamoDB query for getting data with timerange

Tags: python, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to build a query in Python boto3 for the dynamoDB to get the data between the timerange. My table sortkey is timestamp.

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression='deviceid = :deviceid',
    FilterExpression=Key('timestamp').between(':ts1',':ts2'),
    # ExpressionAttributeNames = {"#t": "timestamp"},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':deviceid': {'S': 'BSM_G101'},
        ':ts1': "2021-09-12 10:56:26",
        ':ts2': "2021-09-12 10:57:00"
    }
)
```

The query results in an error:

```
"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeValues unused in expressions: keys: {:ts1, :ts2}"
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the current query and help me correct it?

Answer (score -1):

We can use the KeyConditionExpression  to query using the partition and sort key

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('deviceid').eq('BSM_G101') & Key('timestamp').between("2021-09-12 10:56:26","2021-09-12 10:57:00"),
)
print(response['Items'])
```